# Плавное масштабирование изображения при действии

Tags: html, css, изображения, hover, масштабирование

Есть вот такой [сайт](http://deerdesign.vn/) на нем есть элементы (BEDROOM/KITCHEN/LIVING ROOM) которые при наведении масштабируются не меняя своих размеров. Знаю есть `transform:scale()` но он увеличивает размер, как сделать по типу как на сайте?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Простейший пример

```css
div.block {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 147px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div.block img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}
div.block:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
div.block div.title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}
div.block:hover div.title {background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.39);}
div.block div.title h1 {
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
div.block:hover div.title h1 {opacity:1}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <img src="http://deerdesign.vn/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/PK_Scandinavian-Vintage-1024x755.jpg">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>Текст</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Для кого-то простейший, а для меня пока высшая математика) Спасибо, буду разбирать.